Can not resolve reference 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment' referenced by `X'
I persist a problem using Xamarin for App Androind and iOS , I'm try to install a package 'Xamarin.GooglePLayServices.Base' to project .NET but display the next error message:
Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, referenced by Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, or remove the reference to Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base.  Prueba2.Android
Right now the package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base is installed in Name_Project.Android
This the code of .csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <!--<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>-->
     <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
     <!-- <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework> -->
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2196" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.7.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
    
    
</Project>

I select the next option in the section from Android

And ManifestAndriod this:

